# Anydesk does not display unless the remote host connects to a monitor

Tags: remote-desktop, nvidia-graphics-card, anydesk

I use Anydesk to connect to a remote host (windows 10 + RTX3080), but Anydesk does not show any image unless the remote host is physically connected to a monitor. Anydesk shows that the connection is established but it's waiting for image. It seems that unless the GPU of the remote host is connected to a monitor, it wouldn't send any video signals.

Any solutions? I'd perfer not to use a monitor.

Comment: FYI, this does not match my experience. I use AnyDesk successfully to remote into machines that do not have a monitor attached. Have you ruled out other possible causes, e.g., connectivity issues?

Comment: @yoshm I am not sure. But it's mostly like not caused by the connection itself, since it starts to work the minute I connect a monitor to the gpu. I am suspecting it is due to some gpu setting, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Installing it (used to use portable version) fixed black screen for me. But image is really small